# 7937 segmentation fault (core dumped), busqueda en grafo

Tags: c++, punteros

Tengo este código:

```
int main(){

    dGraph<int> graph;

    graph.addVertex(333);
    graph.addVertex(666);
    graph.addVertex(999);

    //funciona
    //std::cout << graph.searchVertex(2) << std::endl;

    //no funciona -- segementation fault
    //std::cout << std::endl << graph.addRelation(333,9999,2.5);

    return 0;
}
```

La cuestión esta dentro de la función `addRelation()`, la cual agrega una arista(relación) al grafo, esta función usa dentro la función `searchVertex()` y me general el error mostrado.. No termino de comprender ¿por qué?, cuando uso la función de buscar en el main todo funciona correctamente y dentro de la función me genera el error.

Esta es la función de busqueda--

```
template <class rho>
Vertex<rho> *dGraph<rho>::searchVertex(rho data){
    Vertex<rho> *tVertex = _root;

    while(tVertex){
        if(*(tVertex->_data) == data)
            return tVertex;
        tVertex = tVertex->_next;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

y esta la función para agregar una nueva realción--

```
template <class rho>
std::string dGraph<rho>::addRelation(rho origin, rho destiny, double weight){
    
    searchVertex(origin);
    /*
    //pointer of nodes
    Vertex<rho> *tVertexOrigin = searchVertex(origin);
    Vertex<rho> *tVertexDestiny = searchVertex(destiny);

    //not found origin
    if(!tVertexOrigin or !tVertexDestiny) return " :::undefined origin/destiny: -> :not founded::: ";

    //unidirectional realtion
    tVertexOrigin->addEdge(tVertexDestiny,weight);
    
    //bidirectinal relations
    if(!this->_directed) tVertexDestiny->addEdge(tVertexOrigin,weight);*/

    return " :::correctly added::: ";
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, podrias compartir `dGraph`? Asi puedo probar el codigo